# python: sort a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary of type following

```
{id_1 : [ {id_2:score},{id_3:score_2} .... and so on],id_2 :[{id_1:Score_!....]}
```

so basically a nested dictionary
Now I want to sort this dictionary per primary id on the basis of score
so basically

```
{id_1: [{element with max_score},{element_with next max_score....}]... id_2:[{element_with max_score},{element_with next maxx score}...]
```

also, the function should take an argument say (n) which returns the top n matches or if the n< number of elements of that id then it returns teh complete list
any Ideas/ thoughts.. 
Thanks

Comment: You probably have a spurious bracket in the first code snippet -- could you please review this?

Comment: Why are the values of the inner list dictionaries, and not just tuples?

Comment: @SvenMarnach yepp yepp . Thanks for pointing that out.. basically its a nested dictionary

Comment: in-place or you want a new object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter to `list.sort()`.  Assuming the outer dictionary is called `d`, the code could look like this:

```
for scores in d.itervalues():
    scores.sort(key=lambda x: next(x.itervalues()), reverse=True)
```

The lambda function simply extracts the single value of the dictionary.

I think you'd be better off using tuples instead of dictionaries as the values of your list:

```
{id_1: [(id_2, score_2), (id_3, score_3),...], id_2: [(id_1, score_1),...]}
```

Using this data structure, the sorting code would be

```
for scores in d.itervalues():
    scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

or equivalently, but slightly faster

```
for scores in d.itervalues():
    scores.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Should that be `scores.sort(...)`?

Comment: So is d the list.. or a nesteddict??

Comment: +1, might need `reverse=True` as well since the OP wants higher scores first.

Comment: @Jerod I don't understand. This answer contains three possible solutions, and the first one is based on the exact data structure the OP provided. How does this not answer the original question?